# How can i do a mock function with this exemple?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, jestjs

I have this function from `firebase`, and I need a test with it: database.ref(url).remove()

In my action, I have this codes:

```
 const {ref}    = database
 const result   = yield call([database, ref], url)
 const {remove} = database.ref() 
 yield call([result, remove])
```

I need to do a mock function with that function. Database is a object from `Firebase`. Ref and Remove are functions from `Firebase`, but remove is into ref function.

I did like:

```
const databaseMock = {ref: jest.fn()}
const {ref}        = databaseMock
const {remove}     = databaseMock.ref()   //how can i do this correctly?
```

But it doesn't work. How I can do that correctly?

Comment: How *would* that work? How is the `databaseMock` connected to the code under test? Have you read e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks?

Comment: @jonrsharpe In my component i have: `export function* removeProfile(auth, database, action){...}` and in my test i have `const it = sagaHelper(removeProfile(authMock, databaseMock, actionMock))`. I am try this: `it('should call api ref from database', result => {
        expect(result).toEqual(call([databaseMock, ref], url))
    })
    
    const result: {}
    it('should call api remove from database', result => {
        expect(result).toEqual(call([result, remove]))      
    })`

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [mcve].

Comment: for i do this: `database.ref(url).remove()`. I should do this: ` const ref='/users/...'` and  `const databaseMock = {
        ref : jest.fn()
    }
    databaseMock.ref.MockFunction({
        remove: jest.fn()
    })`  ???